# 'GalaSoft' MvvmLight could not be found in Portable project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I have cloned a solution, it contains multiple projects based on GalaSoft MvvmLight library, also it has two Portable Projects. I have installed all required nuget packages and references but I am not able to build these portable projects and its required to build these portable projects first because all other projects reference it. 

I got this(below) error in every file GalaSoft is used. Its a Portable class library project.

> Error 64  The type or namespace name 'GalaSoft' could not be found (are
>   you
>       missing a using directive or an assembly reference

I have referenced this(below) Portable MvvmLight libraries in this project

```
\MvvmLightLibs.4.4.32.7\lib\netcore45\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll
\MvvmLightLibs.4.4.32.7\lib\netcore45\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll
```

and here is the platform target
[image: portable project platform-target]

I have tried cleaning and restarting visual studio. I am stuck at this issue for more than 2 days now. Also, I have tried checking and unchecking "Build" option in Configuration Manager (i have read it somewhere) but didnt work.

Also, there are other 44 warnings. All of them looks similar to below warning.

> Warning   28  The primary reference "GalaSoft.MvvmLight" could not be
>   resolved
>       because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly 
>       "System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>       PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently 
>       targeted framework. ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile158". To 
>       resolve this problem, either remove the reference "GalaSoft.MvvmLight" or 
>       retarget your application to a framework version which contains 
>       "System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>       PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

**EDIT:**
Question title revised

Comment: You need to go bug them on nuget.  Tried installing https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightlibs/ in a PCL targeting 4.0, 4.0.3 and 4.5 and none of the packages would install as they claim they aren't compatible.  This is the package they instruct you to install when your project is a PCL.  Their project that's specifically stated for PCL https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.MvvmLightLibs/ says it's depreciated and to use the MvvmLightLibs package.  So *something* is wrong here on their end.

Comment: @Will I have tried adding \Portable.MvvmLightLibs.4.4.32.1\lib\portable-net45+wp8+win8+wpa81\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll as a reference but still getting same error.

Comment: You can try adding the mayflower while standing on your head, it doesn't matter.  What they *say* is PCL compatible *isn't*.  Your error isn't anything to do with you, it's all their problem.  They are going to have to fix  it, it appears to me.  You should bring this issue to the attention of the Galasoft folks.  I think they're a good bunch and should be willing to help you.  Good luck.

Comment: Anyhow, poked the HDIC, hopefully he'll stop by and help.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that mvvm light has no package targeting your PCL profile.

When you download the package using `nuget install MvvmLightLibs` you can see that the package contains the assemblies for only one PCL profile. Mvvm light supports `portable-net45+wp8+wpa81+netcore45+monoandroid1+xamarin.ios10`. But your PCL targets `.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78`.
If you wan’t your project to be compatible with mvvm light you have to remove the **sl5** target.

[image]